# what is extent(in FS)?

Tags: filesystems, terminology

I was playing with Linux's new FS, BTRFS and was doing some research about it. BTRFS like Ext4 implements extents as allocation unit for data and metadata.
So my understanding is (correct me if I'm worng) that extent is a variable space size of contignuos blocks.
My question is...is one file stored on one extent or multiple...or do they have groups of different extent sizes? 
I'm not really sure how do they map to blocks...

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

> extent is a variable space size of contignuos blocks

Yes.

> is one file stored on one extent or multiple...or do they have groups of different extent sizes

It depends on how fragmented the file is.

From the [BTRFS wiki's glossary](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Glossary):

> **extent**
>
> - Contiguous sequence of bytes on disk that holds file data.
> - A file stored on disk with 3 extents means that it consists of three fragments of contiguous bytes. See *filefrag*. A file in one extent would mean it is not fragmented.

---

> **filefrag**
>
> - A tool to show the number of extents in a file, and hence the amount
>   of fragmentation in the file. It is usually part of the e2fsprogs
>   package on most Linux distributions. While initially developed for
>   the ext2 filesystem, it works on Btrfs as well (but [not really with
>   compressed files](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.file-systems.ocfs2.devel/8894/focus=8902)). It uses the *FIEMAP* ioctl.

---

For example, a 15 GB file on my machine had 22 extents. (Larger files are generally more fragmented.)

An extent is at least 4096 bytes (1 block).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, an extent is a *contiguous* group of blocks.  The allocation size (4KB etc.) determines just how large a single extent can be.  So two things can cause a file to have multiple extents:  1) The file is larger than the largest contiguous free space and 2) The file is larger than the largest possible extent size supported by the allocation size.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still confused on how they map a file to blocks. They are the objects addressed by Inodes and they only group fix or variable number of blocks?